# Opening port 80 on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute node

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

This is an elementary question however one I cannot seem to resolve by perusing the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure documentation. I've created an Ubuntu-based compute node, and it's attached to a subnet. In that subnet I've created a stateful rule with source 0.0.0.0/0, IP protocol: TCP, Source Port Range: All, Destination Port Range: 80.

There is no firewall configured on the server.

Despite this configuration I can't access the compute node's public IP. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a tutorial here, I followed the instruction and it works: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/apache-on-ubuntu/01oci-ubuntu-apache-summary.htm

Answer (score 140, accepted):

When deploying compute instances at Oracle Cloud Infrastructure you need to take into account few things:

1. Create Internet Gateway (IGW).
2. Define routes to point to IGW.
3. Allow port 80 in the Security List associated with the IGW. By default you only have access to SSH and ICMP 3,4 type.
4. Allow connectivity on Compute's instance firewall (which is enabled by default).

In your example if you are using a OEL shape:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=80/tcp

$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Awesome! In my case, ssh(22) worked great, port 80 was not. As I followed all steps above(including "firewall-cmd" steps), the magic happened!

Comment: This worked for me but only after `sudo apt install firewalld`

Comment: the comment above me made all the difference, I had to install the firewall too

Comment: @kimchoky yes I also had the same situation. I can't understand why port 22 would be treated differently. Access via SSH didn't require any setup (except for the keys). But access via HTTP would require more rules. I find it confusing, had no insight, and still can't understand the reason for the difference.

Comment: It is the security list associated with the vcn

Comment: For anyone finding this now and trying to set up an instance, I found by following Oracle's docs on creating the internet gateway (https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/managingIGs.htm) that when I had created my first instance, a lot of this was already created automatically for me. I already had a VCN, a security list with a few ingress rules, notably one that allows SSH (explaining how I was able to SSH into my server before noticing it can't serve HTTP on port 80), and an internet gateway. The subnet in the VCN was already linked to the internet gateway via a route rule.

Comment: However, before being able to accomplish my goals (test serving HTTP on port 80 by installing NGINX, and then set up and connect to a Java Minecraft server), I had to follow the steps given in the other answer here related to `iptables`. Additionally, I found that I wasn't able to connect in to the ports I had unblocked every time the instance was stopped and restarted until I ran the `iptables --flush` command on it after each restart. Because I don't know how iptables works, that's my next thing to learn more about to understand why I had to do this.

Comment: @Constructor I installed the firewalld and I now no longer have SSH access to my system.

Answer (score 167):

I figured it out. The connectivity issue was due to Oracle's default use of iptables on all Oracle-provided images. Literally the very first thing I did when spinning up this instance was check `ufw`, presuming there were a few firewall restrictions in place. The `ufw` status was inactive, so I concluded the firewall was locally wide open. Because to my understanding both `ufw` and `iptables` look at the netfilter kernel firewall, and because `ufw` is the de facto (standard?) firewall solution on Ubuntu, I've no idea why they concluded it made sense to use iptables in this fashion. Maybe just to standardize across all images?

I learned about the rules by running:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Then I saved the rules to a file so I could add the relevant ones back later:

```
sudo iptables-save > ~/iptables-rules
```

Then I ran these rules to effectively disable `iptables` by allowing all traffic through:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

To clear all iptables rules at once, run this command:

```
iptables --flush
```

Anyway, hope this helps somebody else out because documentation on the matter is non-existent.

Comment: Oracle documents the use of iptables instead of ufw and security implications of opening up iptables to all traffic in their best practices documentation:

https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/bestpracticescompute.htm

Comment: WARNING!!!! If you run $iptables --flush, you will lose all access to the machine, essentially bricking it!!!

Comment: I wish it wouldn't have been so hard for me to find this answer.  I don't know why Oracle bothers with adding firewall rules on the server, when everything is protected at the infrastructure level.  Thank you!

Comment: Perfect! Issue Resolve! Why iptables instead on ufw on Ubuntu?
btw, I have zero idea with iptables. How do it make the changes persistent.I have to rerun the commands after server restart

Comment: @Him This did not happen to me. However my machine also didn't become accessible.

Comment: Please, consider the oracle tutorial. It mentioned this issue exactly (look for "Update firewall settings"); https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/apache-on-ubuntu/01oci-ubuntu-apache-summary.htm

Comment: If you do flush your iptables and can't access your instance see https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/serialconsole.htm and the section on "To boot into maintenance mode" you can use the console connection to fix the iptables settings

Comment: Amazing, lots of obscure firewall rules by default... Thanks for this answer, it worked great! About persistence, there are versions of the saved iptables stored at `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `/etc/iptables/rules.v6` (Debian/Ubuntu). You can generate content for these files with `iptables-save` and `ip6tables-save` respectively.

Comment: restoring iptables-rules: `sudo iptables-restore < ~/iptables-rules`

Comment: This was useful. FYI for anyone else who comes across this -- Oracle's default configuration includes rules for iptables but not for ip6tables, leading to inconsistencies between IPv4 and IPv6...

Comment: This solution worked on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish), dated 13th March 2024.

Answer (score 87):

Always refer to the official guide: https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/apache-on-ubuntu/01oci-ubuntu-apache-summary.htm

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ sudo netfilter-persistent save
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: For my single Ubuntu 20.04 instance, I configured Ingress Rules for many other [app required port], such as MySQL 3306 and TightVNCServer 5901, but they are not taking effect. After I executed "sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport [app required port] -j ACCEPT" and "sudo netfilter-persistent save", my instance can be accessed from Internet, magically.

Comment: You also have to allow through the VCN IP restrictions

Comment: this will work on nginx too, thanks.

Comment: This actually worked, thanks! I don't see it mentioned in the linked article though... and I would appreciate an explanation about all the iptables options. It's not trivial to understand what `-m state --state NEW` does from the manpage alone. (**edit**: it's under `Apache` ... but I'm not using apache...)

Answer (score 33):

credited to https://medium.com/@fathi.ria/oracle-database-cloud-open-ports-on-oci-1af24f4eb9f2

Coumputer Instance(Such as Ubuntu) -> Virtual Cloud Network -> Security List -> Ingress Rules -> Please add a rule to allow access to port 80 from anywhere

Comment: THIS is actually what worked for me (except I figured it out on myself, lol).

Comment: That workd ;-) A big headache with this. Lost my time with iptables deal with only

Comment: oh man, a great relief. Thank you a lot man. after 2 days of no sleep. 

but that doesn't make sense. all ports incoming and outgoing are already accepted. why this needed to do. I'm very much curious and confused as well.

Comment: This is all that is needed

Answer (score 21):

### Pre-Requisite

1. VM instance should have been created and running
2. Access to Public and Private keys used during the creation of VM instance

### Log into the VM using SSH and run the following command

```
$ sudo iptables --list --line-numbers
```

It will show the details about Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT). From the list
required to Delete REJECT all rule in the IPTABLES.

```
$ sudo iptables -D INPUT <Reject Line number>
e.g.
$ sudo iptables -D INPUT 6
```

### Check if the REJECT rule is deleted

```
sudo iptables --list --line-numbers
```

### Access the Default Security List and Edit Ingress Rules to Allow Internet Traffic on Port

> Edit the INGRES Rule Add CIDR 0.0.0.0/0 TCP Destination 9999
>   (N): Networking >Virtual Cloud Networks> Virtual Cloud Network Details>Security Lists> Security List Details

### Access your application via web browser

```
Type http://<public IP address of the VM>:port
```

Comment: this is the best answer for me, since it effectively removes iptables from the equation and does not mess oracle rules for the block devices. It's enough protection to have the oci gateway and ingress rules. this is just oracle usual "expert level" requirements...

Comment: this is most appropriate answer

Answer (score 12):

I guess if you add the rule below to your `iptables` it should work; otherwise you'll be disturbing other rules which are related to *block volume attachment* that comes preconfigured on those Oracle images.

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: This command works. To make the changes persistent even after reboot, we need to additionally run: netfilter-persistent save

Comment: I got: iptables: Index of insertion too big.

Comment: @user2650501  the index issue is because of specifying the position `5` for the rule, while if you run `sudo iptables -L` you'll see that your current rules are less than 4 (probably empty).

Comment: to persist (as root - "sudo su"): 
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Answer (score 0):

If you have not created Internet Gateway yet, that might be the reason. In order to connect the VCN with the public internet you need to have an Internet Gateway and a route table to direct the traffic through the gateway.