# Can't let firewall pass port 8065 at Oracle Cloud

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm setting up the service at Oracle Free Tier service; the service is up and running on local interfaces, but I can't reach it from outside (via public IP) on port 8065.

No firewall rules on Ubuntu machine, Oracle firewall is configured and says "TCP traffic for ports: 8065". Exact same (build-in) rule works just fine.

Oracle's Ubuntu default image, Linux's firewall seems to be disabled:

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I'm getting "Connection refused" (TCP level) from outside, when trying to connect.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening port 80 on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794217/opening-port-80-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-compute-node)

Answer (score 1):

it's turned out that a posted answer works - as an Oracle's Ubuntu instance use iptables, so, you need not only to work on the cloud's firewall and ufw, but on iptables level as well, quoting related answer:

[Opening port 80 on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794217/opening-port-80-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-compute-node)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Ubuntu have in build iptables rules in Ubuntu20， you have two choice

1. enable ufw

   ```
    sudo ufw allow HTTP
    sudo ufw enable
    sudo systemctl enable ufw
   ```
2. disable ufw and config iptables

   Sometimes ufw is not Compatible with iptables in Ubuntu20

   such as， if you use mosh need open udp port 60000-61000

   ```
    detele /etc/iptables/rules.v4 and v6
   ```