# Not able to reach the apostrophe-cms server

Tags: apostrophe-cms

So I have installed the Apostrophe-CMS per http://aclouda.com/blog/services/how-to-install-apostrophe-content-management-system-on-ubuntu/ on my Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Ubuntu compute instance and I configured my security list to allow port 3000.

node app.js results in "Listening at http://localhost:3000"

When attempting to reach the server over port 3000 either in telnet or browser, it times out.

Checking `sudo netstat -tunlp | grep :3000` results in:

```
tcp6    0   0 :::3000        :::*        LISTEN     1397/node
```

I am not seeing a tcp 127.0.0.1:3000 line item which I would expect to see. Is there something I need to do to set the app to listen on port 3000 for tcp?

Comment: It is listening over TCP, it doesn't know how to listen over anything else.

Does this work when you run it *on the server itself*?

wget http://localhost:3000/

If so then the firewall is, somehow, still the issue.

However best practice is to set up a frontend proxy such as nginx rather than exposing nodejs directly.

Comment: That's `wget http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: You are right, wget works: Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3000... connected. Though I am not sure what else to change in OCI. The only place they offer is the security list ingress settings which i currently have set to allow all incoming to reach port 3000. This is just a test out the product server, i for sure would do something different if this were to be prod. For now, we are just trying to check the product out. FYI - ufw is disabled. I verified that as well.

Comment: This comment resolved my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54810101/13759151 It is related to iptables that oracle applies.

Comment: Cool, you should post an answer to your own question. Glad you were able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to Oracle using iptables by default. Solution identified in [this stackoverflow comment.](https://www.stackoverflow.com/a/54810101/13759151)