# Opening port 19132 on an Oracle compute instance (ubuntu-20.04)

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I've created an Oracle Cloud infrastructure compute instance running Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to open port 19132.

As per another question I found
[Opening port 80 on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794217/opening-port-80-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-compute-node)

I've created a public subnet which has an internet gateway and added ingress rules for port 19132 (in the security lists)[image: security lists for my vcn]

netstat looks good

```
   netstat -tulpn

    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:19132           0.0.0.0:*                           1007/./bedrock_serv
```

I installed ufw and added rules to allow 19132 but I still can't connect to it from the outside world. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: With Ubuntu are you using iptables? or some other kind of firewall? Does that have the port open as well?

Comment: What does you egress rule look like? May be you need to enable that to allow connections.

Comment: @Joe, iptables has been disabled

Comment: @thanmai, I have setup an egress rule which should allow all outbound traffic

Comment: Silly question: Can you connect to 19132 on the localhost?

Comment: Execute "sudo iptables -I INPUT 6 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport [required port] -j ACCEPT" and "sudo netfilter-persistent save", it works. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648081/3184171

Answer (score 19):

I got the same issue on the Oracle cloud.

Here is what works for me;
First, install  firewalld

```
sudo apt install firewalld
```

Then open the port in public zone;

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=19132/tcp
```

Finally, reload firewalld

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot!, some docs say that you need to set up firewall-cmd using oracle linux, using ubuntu this is the way that I made it work.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me I couldn't get anything to work until I saw this answer. This needs to be boosted.

Comment: Even oracle's own documentation doesn't mention reloading the firewall. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need to have a Public IP configured on that VM for it to be reachable from the internet.

Please look at
https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/managingpublicIPs.htm

For an instance to communicate directly with the internet, all of the following are required:

The instance must be in a public subnet.
The instance must have a public IP address.
The instance's VCN must have an internet gateway.
The public subnet must have route tables and security lists configured accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Harsha, to the best of my knowledge all of the above are already setup - I can use ssh from external as example (22)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned anything about the route table. If missing add to it a route with destination=0.0.0.0/0 and target=the Internet Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions come to mind:

1. You have specified two rules, one for TCP and one for UDP.
   Your netstat shows that something is listening for UDP traffic.  Is
   there also something listening on TCP or are you using UDP only for
   the test?
2. Can you tell us anything about the traffic characteristics
   on this port?  I'm asking because if it is UDP traffic the only way
   for connection tracking to work is to track the source/dest IP and
   port.  Since the port will not be present in fragments, the traffic
   will be dropped. This could be happening on the ingress or egress
   side.  To verify, you could create test ingress/egress rules for all
   UDP traffic to/from your test IP.

Since your ingress rules are stateful, the egress rules shouldn't matter but it wouldn't hurt to double check them.  If none of these things work, you might try a tool like echoping to get more insight into whether or not the traffic is having trouble on the ingress or egress side.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the order of your IPtables rules. Could you post the following command's output for Input chain.

## sudo iptables -S INPUT

I have seen Iptables rules as the single prominent reason for these issues.

Regards
Muthu

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to allow user or add user who can connect like this:

```
create user 'user'@'publicIP' identified by 'password';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'user'@'publicIP' with grant option;
flush privileges;
```

Here publicIP can be '0.0.0.0' or your system IP address.

Don't use '0.0.0.0' as it is open to all, I have faced various breaches on my GCP machine which leads to account block.