# Opening a specific port in Oracle Cloud - Ubuntu 18

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

The above one seems like an easy question, but believe me I have tried multiple methods but all seems to be in vain

For example : Port is 8080

1st - I followed many oracle docs and tried opening port 8080, but failed miserably

2nd - I followed another stack overflow posts - [Opening port 80 on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794217/opening-port-80-on-oracle-cloud-infrastructure-compute-node)

[Opening port 19132 on an Oracle compute instance (ubuntu-20.04)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62778867/opening-port-19132-on-an-oracle-compute-instance-ubuntu-20-04)
still no success

3rd - I followed these oracle instructions and tried to open up the port - https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/developer-tutorials/tutorials/apache-on-ubuntu/01oci-ubuntu-apache-summary.htm

but not working -> to my surprise, when I tried port no 80 with the same method,it worked well..but not working for any other port at all

In short : ** I enabled port 8080 in Security rules in VNC - didnt work

** I tried ,installing `firewalld` and allowing through that -> didnt work for me

** Tried this -> didnt work

```
iptables -I INPUT 5 -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

So I was hoping someone else can find me a solution Please to open up a port, or is there any way to completely disable my firewall so that I can use any port at all - currently I am able to listen to only port 80 from outside

Thank you

Comment: how do you know port 8080 is not opened? (how do you test)

Comment: Hi @Sebas I was using https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to test it

Comment: take a few screenshots of the security list, route table, and instance details, maybe we can spot an omission?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu images in Oracle Cloud seem to have this 'strange' (compared to other clouds) behavior by default where you need to explicitly enable incoming traffic in the VM:

```bash
sudo iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Then you need to make this permanent:

```bash
sudo iptables-save -f /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Oracle Linux and this worked for me.

1. First add a new rule inside the default security list(see the link below)
2. firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp
3. firewall-cmd --reload

Reference : [OCI: Amend Firewall Rules](https://oracle-base.com/articles/vm/oracle-cloud-infrastructure-oci-amend-firewall-rules)

In your case, you have Ubuntu instead of Oracle Linux, so you could try the above two commands as per Ubuntu and check if it works.

Comment: That Reference : OCI: Amend Firewall Rules is the ***only*** answer I found so far that gives the ***proper*** instruction on how to add a new rule inside the default security list, while all other answers missed this must-have step. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

To open a certain port it may require creating a security application specific to the port before creating the security rule. Please refer to this walkthru on it if you haven't already - https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/compute/permitting_public_tcp_traffic_to_compute_instances/permitting_public_tcp_traffic_to_compute_instances.html